# Xamarin Calender Selected Date

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, calendar

I use to Xamarin Calendar my project.

https://github.com/lilcodelab/Xamarin.Plugin.Calendar

I want the listview to load automatically when I select a day on the calendar. Unfortunately, selectedDate is not loading. With the help of a button, I take the selected day and load the listview myself. Without Button. Do you have a suggestion?

```
            <controls:Calendar x:Name="xxcalendar"
                               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            </controls:Calendar>
            
            <Button Margin="50,0,50,0" x:Name="xxbutton" Text="Listview_Loading" CornerRadius="10" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}" Clicked="xxbutton_Clicked"/>

            <ListView>...........</ListView>
```

Comment: "selectedDate is not loading" - what does this mean?  Please post the relevant code and describe exactly what is or is not happening

Comment: Are you using MVVM or MVC? Please include code snippets or we can't help you!

Comment: I have added the relevant codes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Achieved to click on the date to display the events of the day.
2. Achieved to obtain the selectedDate information.

Here is the xaml page:

```
<StackLayout>
    <controls:Calendar x:Name="ca"
        Events="{Binding Events}">
        <controls:Calendar.EventTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout
                Padding="15,0,0,0">
                    <Label
                        Text="{Binding Name}"
                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                        FontSize="Medium" />
                    <Label
                        Text="{Binding Description}"
                        FontSize="Small"
                        LineBreakMode="WordWrap" />
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Calendar.EventTemplate>
    </controls:Calendar>
    <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference ca},Path=SelectedDate}"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is the cs page:

```
public EventCollection Events { get; set; }
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Events = new EventCollection
    {
        [DateTime.Now] = new List<EventModel>
        {
            new EventModel { Name = "Cool event1", Description = "This is Cool event1's description!" },
            new EventModel { Name = "Cool event2", Description = "This is Cool event2's description!" }
        },
        [DateTime.Now.AddDays(5)] = new List<EventModel>
        {
            new EventModel { Name = "Cool event3", Description = "This is Cool event3's description!" },
            new EventModel { Name = "Cool event4", Description = "This is Cool event4's description!" }
        },
        [DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3)] = new List<EventModel>
        {
            new EventModel { Name = "Cool event5", Description = "This is Cool event5's description!" }
        },
        [new DateTime(2020, 3, 16)] = new List<EventModel>
        {
            new EventModel { Name = "Cool event6", Description = "This is Cool event6's description!" }
        }
    };
    BindingContext = this;
}
```

Here is the screenshot：

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer. I added a listview under the calendar. Listview is loaded according to the selected date with the help of a button. What can I do for the selected date to trigger the listview?

Comment: According to the code in my post, I have used  x:Name="ca"  on the xmal page, you only need to use ca.SelectedDate; on the cs page to get the time, and then query the event.

Comment: Use   DateTime dateTime = (DateTime)ca.SelectedDate;   inside the Clicked method of your button to get the date you selected. “ca” is the“ xxcalendar” in your code

Comment: That's the problem. I don't want to use buttons. I couldn't find any event in your calendar that would work for me. I got the result I wanted using the button.

Comment: No matter how you do it, you need a trigger event. I didn’t see this tool trigger the event when the date is clicked.